# No login prompt from Getty over serial console

Tags: serial-port, serial-console, getty, agetty

My Ubuntu 20.04 system has a serial port over which I would like to provide console access.

I can confirm that I can communicate over the serial port with

```
sudo picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyS5
```

I start the Getty instance with

```
sudo systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS5
```

which starts the command

```
/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \u' --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 ttyS5 vt220
```

However, no login prompt appears on the remote system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `strace` to monitor `agetty`'s activity, and I did see that it is writing to and reading from the serial device, even though nothing appeared on the remote side.

After using `strace` to monitor the system calls, I saw that whenever I typed on the remote side, `agetty` was only seeing the byte `0xFF`, which suggested a bad baud rate.

I added a `udev` rule to set the baud rate on the serial device:

```
... RUN+="/bin/stty -F /dev/%k 115200"
```

Since the `serial-getty@.service` passes the `--keep-baud` option, it will use the previously-configured baud rate.